# TypeScript: How to set function return value type based on function argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say there's a function with parameters paramA (string) and paramB (object)

```
const dummyFunction = (paramA: string, paramB: { defaultValue: any }) => {

 }
```

I want to remove the **any** from the *defaultValue* key in *paramB* object (It can be of any type)

Requirement is to give type to function return value based on ***defaultValue*** key in *paramB*. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing which you need is **generics**.

Not sure if I got your intention right, but you would need to go with something like this:

```js
const dummyFunction = <T>(paramA: string, paramB: { defaultValue: T }): T => {

}
```

It will then infer the return type from the type of the `defaultValue`

Comment: Thanks, this helped. 

Had to give <T extends any> before params, if it helps someone

Comment: Try to avoid any as much as possible. 
It good to provide some constraints, but any is not good one ...